# Prometheus Alertmanager Silencing alerts via UI does not prevent first occurence of alert to trigger

Tags: prometheus-alertmanager

Can the ‘Silences’ feature on the Alertmanager UI be used to silence new alerts before they are sent to a receiver? This would be useful while performing an upgrade in an environment.

My alerts contain a label 'env' (to identify a given environment) and I can add a silence rule via the UI.  The problem is that it will only silence AFTER the first occurrence of an alert in the 'env'/environment. In the meantime, an alert has been sent to the Alertmanager receiver.

I have also tried changing values in the alertmanager.conf for 
`group_interval` from 5m to 10s, and `group_wait` from 30s to 60s.

Alternatively, I could update the receiver when there is a match for the 'env' label...but I would prefer to use the 'Silences' feature (either in UI or API - have not tried using the API to do silence).

Any inputs would be appreciated.

(Using version 0.14.0 of Alertmanager)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried silencing in UI as well as throughly Curl(both are alike) You can do in UI itself for betterment and perfection. I did not get any alerts. The moment alerts fired, it was silenced on the first occurrence itself. Kindly let me know what you have tried. May be you can try regex option if you are not sure of the exact value.